# Extended height action bar with pinned bottom Title (Material example)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to replicate the following layout:

[image]

I know I can set its height in my theme:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Actionbar.Tall</item>
```

However this arranges all my views (icons + Title) in the middle (vertically).

One way to solve is it to make the bar translucent without a title and fake its height with a view below it.

Is this the correct way to do it or there a more "correct" approach?

Comment: have you found a solution? I've got the same problem

Comment: @greywolf82 not yet. Just faking it as I explain above.

Comment: Answer from the source now available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491689/how-do-i-declare-an-extended-height-toolbar-action-bar-on-android-lollipop