# Creating a custom toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am trying to create a custom extended toolbar in android with an edit text in the toolbar. The layout that I want to implement looks something like this

[image]

The code that I have written to implement is something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchbox"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Test"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the Activity has the following code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }}
```

But what I get instead is this:
[image]

There are not a lot of tutorials about customizing the extended toolbar so would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231609/creating-a-button-in-android-toolbar/31477092#31477092

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add gravity="bottom" on the Toolbar settings like:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
```

I had to add some margin to the bottom of the layout to get the edit to appear but that should get the Text to the bottom of the edit.

Or you can set layout_gravity on the EditText.

```
        <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/searchbox"
        android:text="Test"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

I'm surprised alignParentBottom compiles. I don't believe Toolbar inherits from RelativeLayout.

Edit - Here's my complete layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="264dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/searchbox"
        android:text="Test"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which results in this:

[image: ToolBar]

Comment: I've tried with that too. It displays it in a weird manner. You can see the results in this screenshot- https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/LKPBxwLnZez8neMwpuaNZXMmjTWbiDyO/Screenshot_2015-05-29-22-29-05.png

Moreover, the problem is also that the width is not properly aligned on both sides of the edit text.

Comment: This problem was seen by more people - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007985/support-toolbars-custom-view-not-using-full-width
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239254/extended-toolbar-with-custom-view-not-displaying-with-full-width
Don't see a clear solution to it though.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you need the added margin on the bottom but that does work as best I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Add some explanations to your answer please.