# Add counter value to Toolbar Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Well,I have a counter value got it from another activity.Now in current activity,with a help of a button,I want to add that counter value on the toolbar(just like any cart:where one item added scenario).Below my receiving intent:

```
public class ShoppingCart extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btn4_s_add,btn5_s_rem,btn6_s_add_to_cart;
private int c_number;
private TextView tv5;
public int counter_s=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shopingcart);

    tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    btn4_s_add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn5_s_rem=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btn6_s_add_to_cart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);


    c_number=getIntent().getIntExtra("counter",0);
    tv5.setText(Integer.toString(c_number));


    btn4_s_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter_s=c_number;
            counter_s++;

        }
    });
    btn5_s_rem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter_s=c_number;
            counter_s--;

        }
    });

    btn6_s_add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter_s=c_number;
            if(counter_s==0){
                Toast.makeText(ShoppingCart.this, "Your cart is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
```

//Now here I want to add the value of counter on the toolbar.Obviously,how do I add badge or other.This is like a checkout button,once you hit,you counter gets visible in toolbar.

```
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

`}`

Comment: should show on toolbar !! like a badge

Comment: You haven't declare any Toolbar in your activity. Furthermore, some layout code of your activity would help us.

Comment: is it solver or not?

Comment: had to use an interface ,declared in adapter and with implement that on m ain

Answer (score 0):

you should customise the `Toolbar`. As it is a `View`. so you can do it easily. you can design a layout in the `toolbar` and place `TextView` in the corner.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_counter" /> 


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now you can access this `textViews` like

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView counter = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_counter);
```

Comment: Did you get your answer? if any issue let me know

Answer (score 0):

Just make your toolbar layout include the tv5 TextView of yours.
In your activity instantiate it:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And get the reference on it, e.g: `tv5 = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv5);`

Then display the counter depending on the button clickplay. Place the following in the onClickListener targetting your button:

```
tv5.setText(Integer.toString(c_number));
tv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In before, you gotta set your TextView invisible i.e:
      `tv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: on toolbar ,like a badge

Comment: I edited my code. By the way i just found the following topic about a button inside a Toolbar, it may give you some last hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231609/creating-a-button-in-android-toolbar

Comment: button is not inside toolbar,it is in activity

Comment: Whatever, just imagine they're talking about a TextView, it remains a basic layout element. What bothers you still?