# Set button on toolbar

Tags: android, menuitem

I want to set SAVE on toolbar on right side but its came in list. I have two menu file 1st one i used for draw able menu and 2nd one is for the SAVE button.

[image: The save button is appearing but its not on the toolbar how can i get this on toolbar]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:title="@string/home"></item>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/quote"
            android:title="@string/quote"></item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/inbox"
            android:title="@string/inbox"></item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/services"
            android:title="@string/services"></item>
    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:title="@string/setting"></item>
    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:title="@string/contact"></item>
       <!-- <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:title="@string/logout"></item>-->
    </group>

</menu>
```

this is second menu for save button

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:title="SAVE"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

this the main activity where i used 1st menu file for drawable navigation view

```js
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu1111; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawe_menu, menu);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      /*  MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.menu.drawe_menu);
        item.setVisible(true);*/
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

i called there methods for 1st menu

and this is the fragmnet where i want save button on toolbar

```js
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflator) {
        inflator.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("", "onOptionsItemSelected");
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.home).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.setting).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.contact).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.quote).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.inbox).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.services).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.save).setVisible(true);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set button by creating your custom toolbar.
Check the link below to set button on toolbar.
 [Creating a button in Android Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231609/creating-a-button-in-android-toolbar)

if you want to add button to your toolbar which will be visible always
then add a button in your toolbar with gravity right

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: then that button will be visible in all layouts

Comment: <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

Comment: where and how it will work if i add this in my fragment

Comment: if i add this in fragment then the drawer navigation will gone or hamburger

Comment: check the post again

Comment: i want button only for 1 fragment, not for all . It should be visible only on 1 fragment

Comment: @NiteshJadhav if you are using viewpager then add pagechange listener in this listener's onPageSelected(int position) if current position != your requiredfragment position hide the button else show

Comment: @NiteshJadhav how do you switch fragments then. please paste the code

Comment: fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

Comment: @Sahil Manchanda i have used this