# Android - Multiple Menus in Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

I added a menu to my `toolbar`, but I don't know how to add multiple menus.

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Share"
          android:id="@+id/main_menu_item_share"></item>
    <item android:title="About"
          android:id="@+id/main_menu_item_about" />
</menu>
```

Comment: can you be more clear or add any image what you really want.

Comment: Go through this. [Creating a buttons in Android Toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31477092/6518860)
It might help

Comment: multiple menu files or menu items??please elaborate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like this it will show 3 menus on toolbar

try like below

```
<item android:id="@+id/common_menu_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/common_menu_settings1"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/common_menu_settings2"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

....
```