# Is it possible to make Toolbar Title as a Hyperlink?

Tags: android, internet-explorer

hi I added link on `toolbar` and gave permission in the manifest but it didnt work. What is mistake?
thanks alot:
in the mainactivity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.asd);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.asd)));
```

**manifest:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**String file:**

```
 <string name="asd"><![CDATA[<h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.google.com">go this page</a></h3>]]></string>
```

Comment: Maybe because this is not the way to do that. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231609/creating-a-button-in-android-toolbar)

Comment: Instead of adding it as a hyperlink provide click on the text and listen to that click.

Comment: @a.dem  you are using fragment or activity