# How to set an OnClickListener on Views of included Layout

Tags: java, android

I have a LinearLayout called pointsContainer in an layout: toolbar. That is included in the main_activity layout. Now I want smth to happen, if I click on the Points container.
I tried to set an OnclickListener in the MainActivity aswell in the Fragment MainFragment which is actually inflated when I click it. My debugger never finds its way into the OnclickListener.

That is my activity_main.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <include android:id="@+id/topbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                 />
                <!--android:elevation="4dp"-->
                <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                 android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" -->



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

That is my toolbar.xml with the container (Linearlayout) I want to click

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#D62D2D"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/variabel_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pointsContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/points_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-12dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="Points:"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thats how I try it in my MainActivity:

```
points = 
findViewById(R.id.topbar).findViewById(R.id.pointsContainer);          
points.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, 
PointsActivity.class));
        });
```

thats how I connect the view in my MainFragment which is inside the MainActivity:

```
pointContainer = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pointsContainer);
```

I tried different ways to connect the views: findViewById(R.id.topbar).findViewById(R.id.pointsContainer);, getActivity.find..., view.find..., etc
I debugged and I tried in the Activity and in the Fragment

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post your code screenshots, instead directly paste your code in the question itself. This will help others to easily try out your code and will help you get answers faster.

Comment: Can you share code of your xml layout as well?

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me on StackOverflow. I edited my initial question and provided the code. Hope it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access the view of the included layout same way you access normal views.

1. For activity

```
pointsContainer = findViewById(R.id.pointsContainer)
```

2. For fragment

```
pointsContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.pointsContainer)
```

The part about click-listener not working is because the `toolbar` overlaps the included `topbar`. You can remove the toolbar if not required.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <include android:id="@+id/topbar"
                layout="@layout/temp"/>
            
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sample Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure if I need the toolbar its really old code. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that everythng builds fine, app gets installed and your desired layout looks like it should be (with extra view on toolbar)

looks like you are initing your custom layout before `Toolbar`, so it may be covered by it (if transparent) and onclick never gets called as touch happens on `Toolbar`, not view visible under it

so try to move `<include` below `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

this may help, but its still not how we should place custom views on `Toolbar`. your included layout should be placed INSIDE `Toolbar` in XML

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
    <include android:id="@+id/topbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar />
```

some example in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405244). you should adjust `toolbar.xml`, at first I see the parent view in it (with `id="@+id/linear"`) have `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, so it may push out other native elements of `Toolbar` (e.g. other custom views or menu) when placed inside

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!