# ToolbarAndroid logo border radius

Tags: android, react-native, android-toolbar

How can I set the border radius of logo image in the ToolbarAndroid component? 
I know it can't be styled by style property.

Comment: hello, did you saw my answer? :-)

Comment: Yup, thank you, I'll try it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two steps:

- create custom `Toolbar` layout with - it' only example - ImageView and TextView
- make an ImageView coreners rounded. Check: [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)
- replace original one with this. Check: [Creating a custom toolbar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534065/creating-a-custom-toolbar-in-android)

Hope help