# Set toolbar title below the toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

How can I place the toolbar title on a different line?

For example "Getting Started" title with its subtitle is on the different line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an `android.widget.Toolbar`, you are looking for the *subtitle*. This can be set in XML:

```
<Toolbar
    android:subtitle="@string/your_string_here"
    .../>
```

Or in code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setSubtitle(R.string.your_string_here);
```

If you are using an AppCompat theme that provides a default toolbar, you can access it via `getSupportActionBar()`. This returns an `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` (or `androidx` equivalent), but the syntax is the same:

```
ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setSubtitle(R.string.your_string_here);
```

Comment: By default toolbar title is placed on the same line as a toolbar, but how can I put it below the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

You might actually want a Collapsing toolbar. Have a look [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/), sample code available there as well

Otherwise you have to [customise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534065/creating-a-custom-toolbar-in-android) the toolbar

> **Hint:** Toolbar can be a container as well. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font/28557209)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom toolbar,so easily create your own design perfection:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This means that you can style the TextView however you would like because it's just a regular TextView. So in your activity you can access the title like so:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```