# Implementing Flexible toolbar with Card toolbar using appcompat v21

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, android-toolbar

I want to implement `Toolbar` something like the following design. It is called flexible toolbar and card toolbar[image]

I tried implementing the custom view inside toolbar. I achieved something like below image![image]

Now what I did is added custom view to Toolbar but I want to implement like first image. I want to create a card like view on tool bar with all those action views.

To achieve that (As per my view) I can create a custom layout and add it over tool bar. Then I should attach another layout below the toolbar.

My question is whether I should do it as what I said or is there any other simpler way I can implement it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848843/how-to-create-a-card-toolbar-using-appcompat-v7/26849046#26849046

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti. I think that might help me. Let me go through it and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 2 ToolBars - One for the "ActionBar" and one for the CardView

```
<FrameLayout>
  <ToolBar /> //the Actionbar ToolBar
  <CardView layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <ToolBar /> //the Toolbar with the Menu items
    ...
  </CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: no thats not the right implementation, you should double your height od the toolbar, you must have only 1 toolbar

Comment: No you must not. what you mean is maybe a the action bar.