# How is this layout implemented?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I'm looking for an implementation of the following layout. How can this be achieved?
[image: Appbar/Toolbar]

It looks like an Appbar with two toolbars.But how can you adjust the white content space to the white toolbar?

I found this layout [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: It looks like a open dialog in an app. Can you provide the link where you found this?

Comment: Sure, follow the link I just added.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848843/how-to-create-a-card-toolbar-using-appcompat-v7) SO question/answer.

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau nope, it's not a dialog

Comment: @Marko: Thanks! I think I have to refine my search ;-)

Comment: @Thomas welcome, hope it will help you :)