# CardView toolbars

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RecyclerView that contains CardViews.

I would like to add a Toolbar to each of those CardViews that would look and behave like the main Toolbar:

[Icon] [Title] .......... [Button] [Button] [Menu]

I've seen from here (http://blog.grafixartist.com/create-a-card-toolbar/) that it is possible to set an actual android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar object inside a CardView.  But it relies on setSupportActionBar(...) to inflate the menu and respond to actions.

Do you think it's possible to reproduce that behaviour in each of my CardViews?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `setSupportActionBar` for your cardviews with toolbars until you would need to set some ActionBar specific actions up/back navigation actions.

Take a look at this fine example (link to whole page below):

> Thanks Gabriele for all the help. Here is working code:
>
> Activity :
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_mai);
>
>       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.card_toolbar);
>       toolbar.setTitle("Card Toolbar");
>       if (toolbar != null) {
>           // inflate your menu
>           toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
>           toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
>               @Override
>               public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
>                   return true;
>               }
>           });
>       }
>
>       Toolbar maintoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
>       if (toolbar != null) {
>           // inflate your menu
>           maintoolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
>           maintoolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
>               @Override
>               public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
>                   return true;
>               }
>           });
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Layout XML File:
>
> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size_x2"
>         android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
>         android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_size"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>         <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>             <LinearLayout
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>                 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>                     android:id="@+id/card_toolbar"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size"
>                     android:background="@android:color/white" />
>
>                 <View
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="1dp"
>                     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
>
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                     android:text="@string/app_name"
>                     android:textSize="24sp" />
>             </LinearLayout>
>         </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```
>
> **Make sure your activity theme is extending** `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.
>
> Here is what it will look like:
>
> [image]
>
> **Few things to note:**
>
> - If you are using card elevation then you need to altar the margin top so that your card aligns with the main toolbar
> - I am still seeing 1-2 pixel margin between bottom of main toolbar and card toolbar. Not sure about what to do in this case. For now, i
>   am aligning it manually.
>
> From: [How to create a card toolbar using appcompat v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848843/how-to-create-a-card-toolbar-using-appcompat-v7)

Notice that author of this post hadn't used it at all, so I'm pretty sure you would also don't need that for implementation your idea

Hope it help

Comment: Quite simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. `setSupportActionBar` is used to set target for `setTitle`, menu inflation and up/back action. You can use Toolbar anywhere you want without using `setSupportActionBar`. It will behave like a ViewGroup.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are correct but I would like to mention they there are times where the menu items become duplicate. In order to get around this, you need to clear the toolbar's menu for each `CardView` by invoking `toolBar.getMenu().clear();`