# How to add a "Share button" to a CardView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a RecyclerView which has many CardViews. Each CardView has a unique ID.

I need to add a button to each CardView so that when the user clicks this button he can share a simple link in the format of "www.domain.com/xx=ID" via Whatsapp or messenger or any other application.

I tried the following code:

```
holder.myBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "text to be shared";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
});
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/UncaughtException: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1597)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1584)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:337)
    at com.myapp.myapp_rental.PropertiesAdapter$4.onClick(PropertiesAdapter.java:229)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5181)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20887)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=ListingActivity, _si=-3768936060483324961, timestamp=1484388033695, fatal=1}]
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.myapp_rental, PID: 20082
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1597)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1584)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:337)
    at com.myapp.myapp_rental.PropertiesAdapter$4.onClick(PropertiesAdapter.java:229)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5181)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20887)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
    I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
    W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
    D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk
    W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
    W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, there is an easy solution for what you have to do.

In layout of Cardview, you can add a Toolbar who contains an Easy Share Action :
[CardView toolbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622621/cardview-toolbars)

In your RecyClerView, each time you called the onBindViewHolder, you can assign items in your menu https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html with link and ID you want.

If you have trouble with RecyclerView and CardView, follow this guide : https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

**Edit** : If you want to share via WhatsApp see : https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012 or use API like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android

I hope I have helped. :)

Comment: i want all apps not only whatsApp.

Comment: my code work fine from activity but when i use it inside cardview it give me the error

Comment: Ha ok, maybe a problem with API of CardView, domains may be different, it's weird. Why do you use "android.content.Intent" one time ans just "Intent" another time ? It's the same package ?

Answer (score 0):

The share buttons you see normally are mostly `ImageViews` with an `onClick` attribute assigned to them. If you want to add the share button to share whatever is on the card just add an `ImageView` in the card layout and to the `ImageView` add the `onClickListener` and add an `Intent` to be deployed.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

You can also add an setType function which can be set to share a link.

Comment: Have you requested for storage permissions? Because to share any data you need storage permissions which you can enable with a pop-up during runtime.