# Crashed when applied Toolbar

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Android programming. I'm having this issue when I applied the toolbar into my app and it crashed when I try to run the app. Here is the code:

```
ToolbarActivity.java

package com.example.toolbar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class ToolbarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toolbar);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

activity_toolbar.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"

        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="page 1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's my **LogCat**:

```
11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.toolbar/com.example.toolbar.ToolbarActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead. 
11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setSupportActionBar(ActionB‌​arActivityDelegateBase.java:165) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.j‌​ava:92) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at com.example.toolbar.ToolbarActivity.onCreate(ToolbarActivity.java:19)
11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 11-23 04:46:35.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): ... 11 more
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem? I had included the appcompat_v7 together with my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see in your logcat output the answer:

Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR, 
  set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Also try using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491689/how-do-i-declare-an-extended-height-toolbar-action-bar-on-android-lollipop)

make sure you use this:

```
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

in your theme

Comment: I'm not quite understand what happen. Previously I had created another project with similar code and it is working.

Comment: Any idea how to change the colour of the text in the toolbar?

Comment: @DanKCl use textColorPrimary attribute in your app theme.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `Toolbar` from v7-support, you should use `Theme.AppCombat` in your `Activity`.

Define your style in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

And apply it to whole application (or specyfic `Activity`) in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: With yours and @SacreDeveloper's help, it's working for now... Thank you!!

Comment: Upvote and accept my answer when it helped, please ;)

Comment: I actually couldn't get this suggestion to work.  If you read the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) you will note that one of the `NoActionBar` themes must be used to prevent the app from using the native class for the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix, it worked for me:

[Link to the StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31475768/1954675)

Also check for the below link for using AppCompat:

[Reference link for the AppCompat library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)